# Returning an enum as an Object type

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I am trying to set the value of a `Field` programmatically by parsing through an xml document to find the values.

My structure is somewhat like this:

```
value = parseXml();
field.set(myObject, value);

private Object parseXml()
{
   String value = getValueFromXmlNode();
   if (type.isInstance(Enum.class))
   {
     return Enum.valueOf(((Class<Enum>) type), value);
   }
   else
   {
     return value;
   }
}
```

This works fine for most cases. However, in the case that the field expects an `Enum`, this no longer works. Because I set the return type of my method as `Object`, the enum gets casted to a String instead. Then the `field.set()` call fails.

What's the proper way to have a method return a generic type that could possibly be an `Enum`?

With primitive types there are Object wrappers that autobox and unbox, does `Enum` have something like that?

Comment: More code please; for instance, what XML API do you use?

Comment: Why does the XML API I'm using matter? This is an issue of design. The reason I left out the code is because it is 300 lines long. I'll fill it with more relevant information.

Comment: Well, not all XML APIs deserialize the same way, and this seems to be a deserialization problem

Comment: Oh I see. I was doing the deserialization manually by calling Enum.valueOf().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because I set the return type of my method as Object, the enum gets casted to a String instead.

No it doesn't.

> With primitive types there are Object wrappers that autobox and unbox, does Enum have something like that?

Enum values *are* objects. You can already put enum values in Object variables.

I believe the problem is with this line:

```
if (type.isInstance(Enum.class))
```

That should be:

```
if (type.isEnum())
```

The `isInstance` call won't do what you want since it's asking if the Class object `Enum.class` is an `instanceof` the `type` class.

Then, because that `if` check doesn't work, it's always selecting the second branch that returns the `String value` as-is, which is why it seems like the enum itself is being cast to a string.

Comment: Ah interesting. I must have misunderstood the isInstance() operator. Similarly, how would I check if the type is a List? I don't see an type.isList() method. `List.class.isAssignableFrom(type)`?

Comment: Yes, `isAssignableFrom()`. If you have a `class X implements List` then `List.class.isAssignableFrom(X.class)` will be true.

Comment: matchedField.getType() => (java.lang.Class) int. Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(matchedField.getType()); => (boolean) false

How come Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(int) is false?

Comment: Well, `isAssignableFrom` was named before autoboxing was added to the Java language which made it possible to write assignments like `Integer i = 5;`. However, the method spec says: "Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter". Which it won't be, because `int.class.getSuperclass()` is `null` (not Integer or even Object). Primitive types are not part of the class hierarchy, even though they have Class objects.

Comment: Hmm for the time being I'll just make sure to only use Integers instead of ints. I wonder if there's a more generalizeable solution

Comment: Solution to what? You can do `intField.set(myObject, new Integer(123));` without problem.

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using `Enum.valueOf(Class, String)` instead of `Enum.valueOf(String)`? You know the value of the String which defines the Enum.

Try to use `Enum.valueOf(value)` instead.

From the javadoc of Enum.valueOf(Class, String): "Note that for a particular enum type T, the implicitly declared public static T valueOf(String) method on that enum may be used instead of this method to map from a name to the corresponding enum constant."

Comment: You can only use `someEnumClass.valueOf(String)` if you have a compile-time reference to the particular enum class. In this case, `type` is a variable. That's what `Enum.valueOf(Class, String)` is for.

Comment: Because he doesn't know the enum type in advance. Edit: Boann said it first.